# Vue - v-model in v-for updating all elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Not sure why this is happening. I have an array of objects that begins like this when the page loads:

```
let members = [ { "firstName": "", "lastName": "", "city": "", "state": "", "email": "", "role": "" }, { "firstName": "", "lastName": "", "city": "", "state": "", "email": "", "role": "" } ]
```

this array is created in the `mounted` life cycle hook, which might make a difference:

```
  mounted() {
    this.members = []
    let numberofGuests = parseInt(this.$route.params.num, 10)
    let emptyArray = Array(numberofGuests).fill(
      { 
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        email: '',
        role: ''
      }
    )
    this.members.push.apply(this.toddsMembers, emptyArray)
  },
```

I'm using this array for my `v-model` like this:

```
<v-row
  class="mb-n5"
  v-for="(member, index) in members"
  :key='index'
>
  <v-col
    cols="1"
  >
    <v-icon
      v-if="members.length > 1" 
      class="ml-4 mt-4" 
      color="#828282"
      @click="removeBrides(index)"
    >remove_circle_outline</v-icon>

  </v-col>

  <v-col
    :cols="columnsTwoAndTwelve"
  >
    <v-text-field
      color="#F03C99"
      label="First Name"
      placeholder="First Name"
      outlined
      :class="marginPositiveLeftWhenStacked"
      v-model="member.firstName"
      @click="setIndex(index)"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
 </v-row>
```

When I update the `text-field` "First Name" ALL the elements in the array get updated and not just the one in the correct position in the array.

Any idea why?

This is using the Vuetify framework as well..

Comment: put :key="index" on your <v-text-field> and that will give each input its own key.

Comment: @jgetner shoot.. no luck

Comment: Could you provide more information? I have no problem on a quick try: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-v-text-field-forked-qb86h?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @ChrisWong definitely.. yea that works perfect.. I'm starting to wonder if its the way I'm creating the array.. I'm creating it on `mounted` I'll explain in my OP

Comment: I suggest provide a minimal working demo such as codesandbox or codepen.